# Generator to replace a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do the following in a cleaner way, and I'd like to use a generator:

```
beta=[] 
for e in shortlist:
    beta.append(np.nanmean(e))
```

where shortlist is where I transformed a list of 50 elements into a list of 10 lists, 5 elements each.
So basically I'm binning my first list and averaging the values.

The results are what I expected: a list of 10 floats, and I can still work with this.

I thought this would work better and look fancier:

```
beta=[] 

[beta.append(np.nanmean(i)) for i in shortlist]
```

I expected a list of ten floats but I get instead:

[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,...

Comment: Do not use list-comprehensions for side-effects, e.g. `.append`. Note, the `.append` method works in-place (a side-effect), and returns `None` (a convention in Python is that methods with side-effects return `None`, is almost always true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're attempting to use the list comprehension here negates most of the benefits of using it. Comprehensions automatically create and return a new list; you don't need to manually create one and append to it.

The elements of the returned list are whatever the left-hand side of the comprehension evaluated to, and `append` returns `None`. Since `append` returns `None`, that's what's added to the list that the comprehension returns.

Just simplify it down to:

```
beta = [np.nanmean(i) for i in shortlist]
#       ^ This is what's added to the list
```

---

And just as a side note, that's not a generator expression that you have there; that's a list comprehension. If you wanted to use a generator expression to make use of the laziness, it would be (note the `()`):

```
beta = (np.nanmean(i) for i in shortlist)
```